# How to build a cordova project in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I want to build my cordova project so I can publish it in the app store.

when i load the project from `./src-cordova/platforms/ios/myapp.xcodeproj` in xcode

And I want to build it I get the following error

```
error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/user/Projects/git/myapp/src-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Cordova/Info.plist' (in target 'Cordova' from project 'CordovaLib')
```

I tried to change the project properties to legacy build and changed the built option `Any iOS device (arm64)` and `any mac (silicon,intel)` but still get the same error.

What to I have to do to build the app so that I can publish it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to delete the cordova project and reinstall it `cordova platform rm ios` and then `cordova platform add ios`